# Is it possible to record audio from just one application on windows?

Tags: audio-recording

I want to be able to record audio from a single application running on Windows 7

So for example, If I want to record application A, and my internet browser plays a noise from a advertisement, the recording does not pick up this noise

I know you can change the volume of all applications independently using the mixer inbuilt to windows, but I want the noise filtered, so I could even watch a film without interupting the recording of sounds from application A.

Comment: Do you have a specialist sound card?

Comment: Nope, just on-board sound. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, but it depends on the software and the sound card.

Sound cards can have multiple inputs/outputs and will allow signals to be routed. Therefore it is possible, if the software allows it, for you to select what output to use. At this point, you can route the signal.

So, based upon the likelyhood of the software giving you this option (which is minimal if not designed to allow this), coupled with an on-board sound card, I'd say no.

Answer (score 12):

Yes it's possible using a software.

You can use a small software called Virtual Audio Cable.
http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm

After installation, it will create a new sound card with a playback on you real sound card. Then by "cheating". You choose the virtual sound card by default then you launch your application. Then choose your real sound card again and you will be able to record from the virtual sound card and listen from your real sound card.

Put every application you want to record on the virtual sound card and it's ok.

Of course in your recording software be careful to choose the right sound card.

Comment: Nice lateral thinking

Comment: But how do you "put" an application on the virtual sound card?

Comment: Hi, you can use this software since windows 10 handle a bit differently the audio system. https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router

Comment: These instructions are not clear enough. I have installed VAC and a "Line 1" "playback device" and "Line 1" and "Mic 1" recording devices have appeared. What exactly I am meant to do then?

Answer (score 1):

This basically requires recording audio from a process instead of system wide audio. It was not possible until now.

A normal recording software will records system wide audio, this is achieved by calling Windows WSAPI API loopback device. This will includes all audio source that active at that time.

Recently a company called D3DGear has developed a technology to record audio just from one process, it will not include background audios from other process. You can check D3DGear to see details of their audio technologies.

Comment: How do applications like D3DGear and Discord get the audio from a single process? Is it some kind of WASAPI extension? Or is it some hack like injecting themselves into the application process?

Comment: People should really say when they're recommending proprietary. A licence for this is currently $30. What this means inevitably (for me and I suspect many others) is that it goes right to the bottom of the list of candidates. There seem to be lots of suggestions for this problem, so even the "15-day free trial" is of no interest, unless NO other solution can be found.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest an quickest way I found was to follow the instructions in [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/217348/how-to-record-the-sound-coming-from-your-pc-even-without-stereo-mix/) and use the [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) audio editing software to record the WSAPI software device. This has the added benefit that you don't need to use different programs to record and edit.

In the Audacity device toolbar (the third toolbar from the top in the default layout) you need to change the audio host (the first drop-down) to "Windows WSAPI". You then need to change the audio device (the second drop-down) to something appropriate - this will vary - you may need to select a loopback device, or you may to just use the same device as with regular recording - some trial and error is needed.

Press record in Audacity, then play the audio in the application you want to record and you should see the waveform appear in Audacity as it records.

Comment: Unfortunately, many W10 OSs don't have either "Stereo Mix" or "What U Hear" as mentioned here: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/ . This is the case with my OS.

Answer (score 0):

> I know you can change the volume of all applications independently
>   using the mixer inbuilt to windows

There is your answer isn't it. Mute sounds from all other applications except the one you want to hear/record

Comment: I could be recording for a while and would like to use my computer normally, (listen to music, watch youtube). But your right this is a definite fall back option

Comment: -1 because you have failed to answer the question. The question is a good one and many, including myself, understand why you might want output from a single app to be channelled into a recording app, while not recording any other sounds being directed to the loudspeakers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from DontPanic57 seems to work for me, but I find his instructions unclear.

This is for Windows 10. Audacity is v. 3.2.1. VAC is 4.6.7.

- download [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/usage.htm) (VAC) - the "Lite" version seems to be free (although the .exe file shows a dialog saying "Trial")
- once installed, there are 4 new items in the Sound dialog (which you access by right-clicking the speaker icon on the taskbar): tab "Playback": "Line 1" and tab "Recording": "Line 1", "Mic 1" and "S/PDIF 1"
- to direct the output from a Net streaming source to "Line 1"
- first go to "Sound settings" (from the start menu)... Advanced sound options --> App volume and device preferences -->
- at the top of this dialog you should see the "default" Output and Input: the default Output should be your system's speakers. the default Input should be your system's microphone (for example).
- in this dialog, find Net streaming source and set the top box to the right (i.e. Output) to "Line 1 Virtual Audio Cable"
- all the other apps listed should have Output and Input set to "Default"
- start Audacity
- click "Audio Setup" --> Recording Device: "Line 1", Playback Device: "Line 1"
- then you can record from your Net streaming source ... the sound goes to Line 1 and thus gets recorded by Audacity.
- but you can also play Youtube (for example) ... and the sound from that is going to the playback device which you select by clicking the speaker icon on the taskbar, and choosing from the list, e.g. your system's speakers
- the output from Youtube then does NOT get recorded in Audacity.
- end the recording in Audacity
- to play back what you have recorded in Audacity, click "Audio Setup", set Playback Device to your system's speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Since may 10, 2022, there's a windows native way to capture an audio stream from a single process. See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/applicationloopbackaudio-sample/).

I don't know any app that actually uses it yet though...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

OBS Studio has a feature "Application Audio Capture (BETA)" to capture specific application / window, see [guide](https://obsproject.com/kb/application-audio-capture-guide).

Since OBS does not allow to output audio only, you need after recording the video/audio file to extract the audio stream with FFmpeg or other tool.

Comment: The 2nd part is not quite right, newer versions of OBS Studio can have custom ffmpeg output to e.g. mp3.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://superuser.com/a/1808614/1145698) [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) answer appeared, but there's a much better way to do it with that tool:

- firstly, install [win-capture-audio](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/win-capture-audio.1338/) plugin. It's still much better than the default OBS functionality of limiting to a single app or matching windows. E.g. it can limit to multiple processes or everything except multiple processes. It also works more consistently from my experience on Windows 10 and OBS 29.1.3.
- add `Application Audio Output Capture` source (not the `BETA` one) and configure it to your liking
- lastly, go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Output`, make sure `Advanced` mode is selected. Open `Recording` tab and choose `Custom Output (FFmpeg)` in dropdown. Choose e.g. `mp3` as container, disable `Video encoder` and edit the rest of settings to suit your needs.

This will save the output to `.mp3` directly and you can use a separate profile for that in case you're also using OBS for normal video recording.

Answer (score -1):

On Mac systems a small developer, Rogue Amoeba, created an app named Audio Hijack. Which is an application with the sole purpose of recording other applications audio sources. I highly recommend it even when you requested a Windows alternative, I would consider some kind of boot system or separate device for this type of action.